# SSME/RS-25:; Why arent high pressure and low pressure pumps coaxial?

Tags: engine-design, design-alternative, ssme

The Space Shuttle Main Engine low pressure pumps to prevent cavitation at the main pumps. This pumps were driven by separate turbines fed by high pressure fluid from the main pumps. Why? It just adds additional ducting complexity. Why couldn't they also be driven by low RPM turbines on the concentric shafts with the main pumps, powered by the preburners, similar to how jet engines work?

Comment: (wild guess) Possibly it's desirable to control their power individually?

Comment: @OrganicMarble or you could just add another turbine like virtually everyone else...

Comment: Yeah, your "the same shaft" fooled me, because it's incorrect. Jet engines have concentric spools/shafts rotating at different speeds. Is that what you are proposing?

Comment: @OrganicMarble yes, correct. Sorry for that cinfusion

Comment: Anyway, the low pressure pumps were mounted on the vehicle - they didn't even gimbal. It would have been impossible/impractical to physically connect them with a shaft to the high pressure turbines. You might be able to make a design like you propose, but it would be a completely different engine. https://space.stackexchange.com/q/35995/6944

Comment: @OrganicMarble was it important that the low pressure pumps must not gimbal?

Comment: @Abdullah see the question link I added to the comment.  Obviously it was important or they wouldn't have done it. Exactly why is not exactly written on this site. I think the answer there is probably right, but I'd love to see a definitive reference.

Comment: @OrganicMarble are the high pressure lines really any smaller?

Comment: Looks like it. See page 2-6 here https://ia800704.us.archive.org/13/items/PocketDataRIRD87142SpaceShuttleMainEngine/Pocket_Data_RI-RD87-142_Space_Shuttle_Main_Engine.pdf